# Openstreetmap of a specific city of USA

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to get the osm of a specific city of USA. I can only get the whole state now. But how can I get the osm data for a specific city.

Comment: Which City? and what format do you want it in?

Comment: I want it for Minneapolis in osm format

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts.

I have previously used http://extract.bbbike.org. If you know the approximate latitude and longitude coordinate pairs for your city, it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

**Downtown Minneapolis in osm.xml format**

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=44.97649&lon=-93.26969&zoom=15&layers=M
Export>OpenStreetMap XML Data

**NOTE if your area [Bounding Boxing] exceeds 50,000 nodes you WILL require to use the planet.osm file see DMan answer for this method

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mike Migurski provides city-level abstracts of OSM at [metro.teczno.com](http://metro.teczno.com/#mpls-stpaul), including for Minneapolis.

Comment: They are now located here: https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/

Answer (score 0):

Try using inViu routes. It's a free GPS tracking Android app that uses OSM. The data from the app can be exported as a GPX file.

The developers are huge supporters of OSM. https://www.enaikoon.com/en/module/footer-blocks/about-us/openstreetmap/

You can download inViu routes in Google Play: http://tiny.cc/i49jpw